# pexpect timeout with large block of data from child

Tags: python, timeout, pexpect

I am using pexpect to call another python script (py27) that prompts for raw_input. I'm trying to build a GUI wrapper around this script without modifying it.

The problem I have is that the script I call has a large amount of data returned when executing (e.g., 10KB) before the next command prompt. I am aware that pexpect struggles with large amounts of data. The `child.expect` call always hits the timeout, no matter what value I pass it. How do I deal with large data sets? I've learned ways to manage this with manual reads `child.expect.read(X)`, but this is hacky. There's some sort of buffering going on and I don't know how to work around it cleanly. The script return data is not to throw away and needs to be parsed so I can't just have a thread always reading, unless it could somehow write to a file.

EDIT:

Here is an example. I'm on Windows 10 and using Py2.7

test2.py (can modify this script, but not test1.py)

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn
import time

child = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("python test1.py", maxread=1)
# send hello to child
child.sendline("hello")
# wait for command prompt ">"
child.expect(">", timeout=30)
```

test1.py (models behavior of my real script, prints a large block of data at beginning, returns ">" as a prompt when a command completes, can't modify this script)

```
import sys

# print a bunch of data
for i in range(2000):
    print(i)

try:
    while True:
        # ask for input
        x = raw_input(">")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit("Manually quit")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 23, in 
    child.expect(">", timeout=10)
  File "C:************\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 327, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "C:************\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 355, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "C:************\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 106, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "C:************\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 70, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: 
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(">")

searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(">")

Comment: How much data did you get from the 10KB output before the timeout?

Comment: With a timeout of 30 sec and 60 sec the logfile size is always 4231Bytes. So it has nothing to do with the timeout as far as I can tell.

Comment: How much time does it take to output the 10KB data if you run the command manually?

Comment: hacked in timestamps with datetime. When running the script manually it takes 0.029 seconds for the 10kB of data to display.

Comment: No idea what's wrong. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that prompt will appear definitely and your scenario is ok to wait forever then using timeout=None in the expect will wait indefinitely for the prompt to appear.
But yes waiting indefinitely has its own negative consequences. 
I would suggest to use this approach only if 100% sure that prompt will appear and waiting indefinitely is not a problem.

Comment: With the new example code I pasted above changing to "None" hangs forever.