# Running multiple Bash commands interactively from Python

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I have just come across `pexpect` and have been figuring out how to use it to automate various practices I would otherwise have to fill in manually in a command shell.

Here's an example script:

```
import pexpect, sys

child = pexpect.spawn("bash", timeout=60)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.sendline("cd /workspace/my_notebooks/code_files")
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('ls')
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('git add .')
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('git commit')
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('git push origin main')
child.expect('Username .*:')
child.sendline(<my_github_username>)
child.expect('Password .*:')
child.sendline(<my_github_password>)
child.expect('#')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

(I know these particular tasks do not necessarily require `pexpect`, just trying to understand its best practices.)

Now, the above works. It `cd`s to my local repo folder, lists the files there, stages my commits, and pushes to Github with authentication, all the while providing real-time output to the Python stdout. But I have two areas I'd like to improve:

Firstly, `.expect('#')` between every line I would run in Bash (that doesn't require interactivity) is a little tedious. (And I'm not sure whether / why it always seems to work, whatever was the output in stdout - although so far it does.) Ideally I could just clump them into one multiline string and dispense with all those `expect`s. Isn't there a more natural way to automate parts of the script that could be e.g., a multiline string with Bash commands separated by ';' or '&&' or '||'?

Secondly, if you run a script like the above you'll see it times out after 60 seconds sharp, then yields a TimeoutError in Python. Although - assuming the job fits within 60 seconds - it gets done, I would prefer something which (1) doesn't take unnecessarily long, (2) doesn't risk cutting off a >60 second process midway, (3) doesn't end the whole thing giving me an error in Python. Can we instead have it come to a natural end, i.e., when the shell processes are finished, that's when it stops running in Python too? (If (2) and (3) can be addressed, I could probably just set an enormous `timeout` value - not sure if there is better practice though.)

What's the best way of rewriting the code above? I grouped these two issues in one question because my guess is there is a generally better way of using `pexpect`, which could solve both problems (and probably others I don't even know I have yet!), and in general I'd invite being shown the best way of doing this kind of task.

Comment: I'd say best would be not needing user input at all: [configure GitHub with public key authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), then run a script non-interactively.

Comment: Yes I know, I do that. This is an example regarding how to properly/best use `pexpect` (as I tried to make clear). Hence why `git` is not a tag

Comment: My comment's core remains the same: if at all possible, not using `pexpect`, because it is super rare to find a task that _needs_ to be interactive; typically just executing a script with appropriate standard input is enough. It is almost always an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As I gave the solution for `git`, most other use cases of `pexpect` can be solved by other means that don't have the drawbacks of `pexpect` (that you correctly identified in your post).

Comment: Usually, the best approach is not to use pexpect. Command outputs easily change and aren't documented with programmatic use in mind. In other words, it is hard to plan ahead on all output possibilities and handling them correctly.

Comment: "What's the best practice for doing X?" is [generally too broad to be on-topic here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353). If you're looking for an example that solves every possible problem you could hit, in particular, that's a request for a very large number of answers to a very large number of questions. There are certainly workarounds for various issues (generating a UUID to use as a prompt, f/e); but those are all their own questions and _in general_, the best practice is not to use pexpect unless you have no other option.

Comment: (Software that prompts from stdin rarely specifies the form and order of those prompts as part of that program's compatibility guarantees, since the expectation is that there will be a human on the other end who can observe that a new version added an additional prompt that needs to be answered _before_ one can see the username or password prompt, or that some rare runtime circumstance changes the prompting, f/e; and that's before we start worrying about language and locale concerns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wait for `#` between each command. You can just send all the commands and ignore the shell prompts. The shell buffers all the inputs.

You only need to wait for the username and password prompts, and then the final `#` after the last command.

You also need to send an `exit` command at the end, otherwise you won't get EOF.

```
import pexpect, sys

child = pexpect.spawn("bash", timeout=60)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.sendline("cd /workspace/my_notebooks/code_files")
child.sendline('ls')
child.sendline('git add .')
child.sendline('git commit')
child.sendline('git push origin main')
child.expect('Username .*:')
child.sendline(<my_github_username>)
child.expect('Password .*:')
child.sendline(<my_github_password>)
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('exit')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

If you're running into the 60 second timeout, you can use `timeout=None` to disable this. See [pexpect timeout with large block of data from child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413407/pexpect-timeout-with-large-block-of-data-from-child)

You could also combine multiple commands in a single line:

```
import pexpect, sys

child = pexpect.spawn("bash", timeout=60)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.sendline("cd /workspace/my_notebooks/code_files && ls && git add . && git commit && git push origin main')
child.expect('Username .*:')
child.sendline(<my_github_username>)
child.expect('Password .*:')
child.sendline(<my_github_password>)
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('exit')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Using `&&` between the commands ensures that it stops if any of them fails.

In general I wouldn't recommend using `pexpect` for this at all. Make a shell script that does everything you want, and run the script with a single `subprocess.Popen()` call.

Comment: I'd at least want to put some `|| exit`s into those commands so our failure modes don't include running commands in the wrong directory. `git add .; git commit; git push origin main` can be quite destructive if run in the wrong place!

Comment: While this addresses part of the question (I did upvote it), do note that this will still timeout after 60 seconds, and it may still fail if any of the files in that directory is named `Password :` (unlikely as it is), and it may still fail if `PS1` does not include `#`.

Comment: @Amadan Obviously the code is expecting a `#` prompt. Although that seeems weird, since that's usually only in root's prompt, and I can't see why someone would be pushing to git from the root account.

Comment: It's hard to write something like this without making assumptions about the prompt.

Comment: I mean, one could explicitly set `PS1` for that environment in order to control as many variables as possible. But there are still variables, which is why I suggest not using `pexpect` if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you. What about the possibility of submitting multiple commands chained (like CharlesDuffy's dangerous `git add .; git commit; git push origin main` chained with `;`)? Can we write the first few commands (up to `git push origin main`) in a single string, or does `.sendline()` only accept individual separated commands? (If we could then I assume we could also include something like `cd <dir> &&` so we don't end up executing the subsequent commands if the directory doesn't exist.)

Comment: You can do that. `pexpect` doesn't know anything aboutthe shell or  commands, it's just sending lines.